# Why me getting this message when i run npm list react after upgrading Reacts Js version fro 17 to 18

Tags: reactjs

```
master-app@0.1.0 
+-- @testing-library/react@11.2.7
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- @varld/popover@0.1.0
| +-- react-popper@2.3.0
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped invalid: "^16.3.2 || ^17.0.0" from node_modules/react-accessible-accordion, "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0" from node_modules/react-html-parser, "<= 16.x.x" from node_modules/react-truncate
| +-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| `-- use-delayed@0.1.0
|   `-- react@18.2.0 deduped invalid: "^16.3.2 || ^17.0.0" from node_modules/react-accessible-accordion, "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0" from node_modules/react-html-parser, "<= 16.x.x" from node_modules/react-truncate
+-- react-accessible-accordion@3.3.5
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped invalid: "^16.3.2 || ^17.0.0" from node_modules/react-accessible-accordion
+-- react-datepicker@4.16.0
| +-- react-onclickoutside@6.13.0
```

I have upgraded reacts version from 17 to 18